# find the number of orders per customer

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

i am trying to display the number of orders for each customer as a dbms_output.put_line but the count is not correct...what am I doing wrong??

```
declare
  t_order       number;
  cust_id       customer.c_id%type;
  orders_cid    orders.c_id%type;
  cust_first    customer.c_first%type;
  cust_last customer.c_last%type;

  cursor c is
    select distinct(customer.c_id),
           customer.c_first,
           customer.c_last,
           orders.c_id
      from customer
      join orders
        on customer.c_id = orders.c_id;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('AZ SPORTS OUTSTANDING ORDERS');
  dbms_output.put_line('FIRST   LAST    TOTAL');
  dbms_output.put_line('NAME    NAME    ORDERS');

  OPEN C;
  LOOP
    FETCH C INTO CUST_ID, CUST_FIRST, CUST_LAST, ORDERS_CID;
    EXIT WHEN C%NOTFOUND;

    IF CUST_ID=ORDERS_CID THEN
      select count(distinct(orders.c_id))
        into t_order
        from orders
        join customer
          on orders.c_id = customer.c_id

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(CUST_FIRST) || ' ' ||
                           TO_CHAR(CUST_LAST)  || ' ' ||
                           TO_CHAR(T_ORDER));
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE C;
END;
/
```

The number of orders per customer is displaying 5 all the way down for each customer which isnt the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you need a WHERE clause on the `SELECT COUNT...` statement - perhaps something like `WHERE ORDERS.C_ID = ORDERS_CID AND CUSTOMER.C_ID = CUST_ID`. Try that and see how it works.

Share and enjoy.